# Reposition controls after form resize event

Tags: c#, winforms

I feel this is an easy one and I'm going to het palm face when I get the answer. I need to issue new location to some controls after `WinForm` `SizeChanged` event.

```
private void DocumentCenterForm_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            pdfViewer.Location = new Point(0, 236);
            pdfViewer.Update();
            this.Update();        
}
```

But my control would not move. Please help.

Comment: Your control would not move because you are specifying a fixed location.

Comment: You might also want to handle the [`Layout` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.layout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) instead of the `SizeChanged` event. This is invoked whenever the layout needs to change, including SizeChanged, but there also other events that can require Layout to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You're always setting `Location` to `new Point(0, 236);`. You should use the `Width` and `Height` properties of `DocumentCenterForm` if you want it to dynamically change based on the size change.

Answer (score 0):

As suspected: palm-face. The control was docked so to change position one must change height too.